# Facebook Open graph api in iphone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using Facebook open graph for publishing my story.I was able to publish it on my timeline.My problem is the occurrence of keyword in the story.
My story is published as A won a points from B.
Here a is my action and B is my object.I want to remove 'a".
ie I need to publish it as A won points from B.

Is it possible to remove such keywords?
Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the determiner of an object type, only for a specific object title. You're going to have to rethink your story, like maybe "A won a game from B" and then put the score in the description.